# How to calculate a PDF of a neural network output?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, machine-learning, neural-networks

I have to find the probability density function of the output of an internal layer in a neural network.

I wanted to do it using `NetMeasurements` adding a layer like

`ElementwiseLayer[BinCounts[{#}, {0, 1, .05}] &]`

to my `ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid]` and measuring its average over the dataset. However, I get the error that it "could not be symbolically evaluated as a unary scalar function."

Therefore I have to apply `NetMeasurements` to each element of the dataset to get the output of my layer and then calculate `BinCounts`, which is very slow.

Is there a way to calculate PDFs of the layer's output faster?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how one can implement `BinCounts` as a layer:

```
ClearAll[binCountsLayer];

binCountsLayer[{start_, end_, step_}] :=
 NetChain[{CompiledLayer[
    Function[{Typed[input, 
       TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"]["Real64", 1]]}, 
     Quotient[Clip[input, {start - step, end}] - start, step] + 2], None],
   UnitVectorLayer[Quotient[end - start, step] + 2], 
   AggregationLayer[Total, 1], PartLayer[2 ;; -2]}]
```

#### Test

```
Block[{temp = RandomReal[{-10, 20}, 50]},
 {binCountsLayer[{0., 10., 1.}][temp], BinCounts[temp, {0, 10, 1.}]}
 ]

(* Out: {{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1},
         {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1}} *)
```

```
Block[{temp = RandomReal[{-1, 2}, 50]},
 {binCountsLayer[{0., 1., .25}][temp], BinCounts[temp, {0, 1, .25}]}
 ]

(* Out: {{5, 5, 6, 3},
         {5, 5, 6, 3}} *)
```

Note that the `input` with `start`/`end`/`step` arguments should be the same type specified in the `CompiledLayer` (`Real64`).